# finding the most popular word in a person's tweets

Tags: java, string, list, hash, iterator

In a project, I'm trying to query the tweets of a particular user's handle and find the most common word in the user's tweets and also return the frequency of that most common word.

Below is my code:

```
  public String mostPopularWord()
  {
     this.removeCommonEnglishWords();
     this.sortAndRemoveEmpties();

     Map<String, Integer> termsCount = new HashMap<>();
     for(String term : terms)
     {
        Integer c = termsCount.get(term);
        if(c==null)
           c = new Integer(0);
        c++;
        termsCount.put(term, c);
     }
     Map.Entry<String,Integer> mostRepeated = null;
     for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> curr: termsCount.entrySet())
     {
         if(mostRepeated == null || mostRepeated.getValue()<curr.getValue())
             mostRepeated = curr;
     }

     //frequencyMax = termsCount.get(mostRepeated.getKey());

     try 
     {
        frequencyMax = termsCount.get(mostRepeated.getKey());
        return mostRepeated.getKey();
     } 
     catch (NullPointerException e) 
     {
        System.out.println("Cannot find most popular word from the tweets.");
     }

     return ""; 
  }
```

I also think it would help to show the codes for the first two methods I call in the method above, as shown below. They are all in the same class, with the following defined:

```
  private Twitter twitter;
  private PrintStream consolePrint;
  private List<Status> statuses;
  private List<String> terms;
  private String popularWord;
  private int frequencyMax;

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public void sortAndRemoveEmpties()
  {
     Collections.sort(terms);
     terms.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null));
  }

  private void removeCommonEnglishWords()
  {          
     Scanner sc = null;

     try
     {
        sc = new Scanner(new File("commonWords.txt"));
     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
        System.out.println("The file is not found");
     }

     List<String> commonWords = new ArrayList<String>(); 
     int count = 0;
     while(sc.hasNextLine())
     {
        count++;
        commonWords.add(sc.nextLine()); 
     }

     Iterator<String> termIt = terms.iterator();
     while(termIt.hasNext())
     {
        String term = termIt.next();
        for(String word : commonWords)
           if(term.equalsIgnoreCase(word))
              termIt.remove();
     }
  }
```

I apologise for the rather long code snippets. But one frustrating thing is that even though my removeCommonEnglish() method is apparently right (discussed in another post), when I run the mostPopularWord(), it returns "the", which is clearly a part of the common English Words list that I have and meant to eliminate from the List terms. What might I be doing wrong?

UPDATE 1:
Here is the link ot the commonWords file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VKNI-b883uQhfKLVg-L8QHgPTLNb22uS/view?usp=sharing

UPDATE 2: One thing I've noticed while debugging is that the 
while(sc.hasNext())
in removeCommonEnglishWords() is entirely skipped. I don't understand why, though.

Comment: *apparently* right? Make that a certainty first. Inspect the content of the list after that method has been called, and see if it contains "the" or not. Your debugger, as well as System.out.println(), are your friends.

Comment: Is it possible for you to post ```commonWords.txt``` also, so that we can try the code?

Comment: @SreeKumar It has now been posted as an update above.

Answer (score 2):

It can be more simple if you use stream like so :

```
String mostPopularWord() {
    return terms.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
            .findFirst()
            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
            .orElse("");
}
```

Comment: I was returned a cannot find symbol—is there anything I should be importing before running this?

Comment: @singularity What did you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. Here is what you will have to do. Replace the following part in `removeCommonEnglishWords()`

```
Iterator<String> termIt = terms.iterator();
while(termIt.hasNext())
{
   String term = termIt.next();
   for(String word : commonWords)
      if(!term.equalsIgnoreCase(word))
           reducedTerms.add( term );
}
```

with this:

```
 List<String> reducedTerms = new ArrayList<>();
 for( String term : this.terms ) {
     if( !commonWords.contains( term ) ) reducedTerms.add( term );
 }

 this.terms = reducedTerms;
```

Since you hadn't provided the class, I created one with some assumptions, but I think this code will go through.

Comment: oh thank you—I'll try that. Could you also have a look at my Update 2 above, though? That seems to be a problem as well.

Comment: @singularity About Update 2: I am not sure why that is happening. It is neatly going through into the loop in the modified code I gave, on the Eclipse on my system. Hope you have tried the basic stuff of Clean-Build, etc.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it still doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach using streams.

1. This uses the relatively common frequency count idiom using streams and stores them in a map.
2. It then does a simple scan to find the largest count obtained and either returns
   that word or the string "No words found".
3. It also filters out the words in a `Set<String>` called `ignore` so you need to create that too.

```
           import java.util.Arrays;
           import java.util.Comparator;
           import java.util.Map;
           import java.util.Map.Entry;
           import java.util.stream.Collectors;

            Set<String> ignore = Set.of("the", "of", "and", "a",
            "to", "in", "is", "that", "it", "he", "was",
            "you", "for", "on", "are", "as", "with",
            "his", "they", "at", "be", "this", "have",
            "via", "from", "or", "one", "had", "by",
            "but", "not", "what", "all", "were", "we",
            "RT", "I", "&", "when", "your", "can",
            "said", "there", "use", "an", "each",
            "which", "she", "do", "how", "their", "if",
            "will", "up", "about", "out", "many",
            "then", "them", "these", "so", "some",
            "her", "would", "make", "him", "into",
            "has", "two", "go", "see", "no", "way",
            "could", "my", "than", "been", "who", "its",
            "did", "get", "may", "…", "@", "??", "I'm",
            "me", "u", "just", "our", "like");


            Map.Entry<String, Long> entry = terms.stream()
                 .filter(wd->!ignore.contains(wd)).map(String::trim)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a -> a,
                        Collectors.counting()))
                .entrySet().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.maxBy(Comparator
                        .comparing(Entry::getValue)))
                .orElse(Map.entry("No words found", 0L));


              System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue());
```

Comment: I was returned a cannot find symbol—is there anything I should be importing before running this?

Comment: Sorry about that.  Try it now.  Otherwise, I don't know what is going on.

Comment: I just realized you also wanted the frequency so I made a slight change to include that too.